How to pass authorization header via Axios with OAuth token not Bearer token
I am trying to pass an access token header to a REST API server and is not working with Node.js Axios.
This command works with curl:
curl --location 'https://.../api/get-somedata' --header 'Authorization: OAuth aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa'
My node.js code looks like this:
    const token = 'aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa'
    const url = 'https://.../api/get-somedata'
    const headers = {
        Authorization: "OAuth " + token
    }
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(url, '', { headers: headers })

        return response
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        return "Unable to get some data"
    }

'Error: Request failed with status code 401\n    at createError ...
The administrator of the REST API server told me that this wasn't a Bear token but an OAuth token. In Postman, it looks like the screenshot, and I can get a response fine:

Does anyone know how to accomplish it with Axios?
Tried with curl command or Postman
With Node.js, I tried a header with
const headers = {
    Authorization: "Bearer " + token
}

But I received an error message.
